# Omitted verb: "Qual" e "Qual é" em perguntas

Tags: verbos, sintaxe

##### Portuguese

No Brasil, é comum é omitir o verbo *ser* em perguntas no formato **qual é o/a...**. Por exemplo:

> Qual é o seu nome?

ou

> Qual o seu nome?

As duas variações são corretas segundo a gramática normativa? Existe alguma diferença de sentido, mesmo que sutil entre elas? O que leva ao uso de uma ou outra?

---

##### English

In Brazil it's common to omit the verb "ser" in questions of the form "qual é o/a" ("What is the"). For instance:

> Qual é o seu nome?  [What is your name?]

or

> Qual o seu nome?  [What your name?]

Are both constructions correct according to normative grammar? Is there any difference in meaning, even if subtle, between them? What leads to one or the other being preferred?

Comment: É comum em Portugal também. "Qual a razão deste atraso?"

Comment: Penso que a segunda é coloquial e formalmente estaria incorreta pois está a formar uma pergunta sem usar nenhum verbo.

Comment: nem toda frase precisa de um verbo, frase com verbos são orações.

Comment: bfavaretto, Achei por bem adicionar uma versão em inglês da sua pergunta, após fechar como duplicata uma pergunta equivalente, mas escrita nesse idioma. Por favor não hesite em retificar qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As duas variações são corretas segundo a gramática normativa?

Sim. "Qual", neste contexto (tempo presente), é um [pronome interrogativo que transmite a ideia de seleção](http://www.normaculta.com.br/pronomes-interrogativos/). Portanto, o verbo "ser" pode ser omitido sem prejuízo semântico na frase.

Há poucas fontes mesmo, mas a mais objetiva que encontrei é [*link não mais funcional*] [este áudio do Professor Pasquale explicando a omissão no colóquio da língua](http://radioglobo.globoradio.globo.com/com-a-palavra,-o-professor-pasquale/2013/03/08/QUAL-O-SEU-NOME-OU-QUAL-E-O-SEU-NOME.htm).

### Existe alguma diferença de sentido, mesmo que sutil entre elas? O que leva ao uso de uma ou outra?

No presente do indicativo, não. Em outros tempos verbais, sim.

> Qual foi sua profissão?
>
> Qual será a cidade que escolherá para viver?

Comment: Nesse link diz que o verbo pode ser omitido? Não vi isso. Não sei não, ainda estou em dúvida...

Comment: Acho que li errado o link. Coloquei mais um.

Comment: É, o Pasquale deve ter razão: é da língua, é usado em todos os registros. Então é aceito pela norma culta. Mas às vezes a gente pode achar estranho, como eu e o Ualisson achamos.

Comment: @LeonelSanchesdaSilva Infelizmente o link para sua principal fonte deixou de funcionar. Será que você conseguiria achar um substituto?

Answer (score 2):

#### Portuguese

O nome dessa figura de linguagem é **elipse**, que [ocorre](https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/elipse.html)

> quando um termo é omitido em um enunciado, mas fica subentendido pelo contexto.

Note que o termo omitido é indispensável (a pergunta é "Qual **é** seu nome?"), e que a elipse é apenas aceitável na mesma proporção em que sua presença implícita estiver clara.

Ou, nas palavras de [Sérgio Nogueira](https://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/45.html):

> É importante observar que a boa elipse é aquela que não prejudica a clareza da frase.

Que também coloca:

> não devemos reduzir tudo à simplista discussão de certo ou errado.

O que nos leva à pergunta:

> As duas variações são corretas segundo a gramática normativa?

Sim, ou melhor, ambas *podem* estar corretas, desde que a omissão não prejudique a compreensão da frase. Mas em um contexto formal, e especialmente por escrito, é importante aplicar esse critério com especial rigor e, na dúvida, evitar a elipse.

> Existe alguma diferença de sentido, mesmo que sutil entre elas?

O significado básico é o mesmo, mas a elipse tende a conferir um caráter mais coloquial à frase; também é mais concisa — mas o efeito disto, se houver, depende do contexto.

> O que leva ao uso de uma ou outra?

Como com outras construções coloquiais, o hábito e a (percepção de) facilidade são as principais motivações para seu uso.

---

#### English

This figure of speech is called [**ellipsis**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ellipsis):

> **1.a.** The omission of a word or phrase necessary for a complete syntactical construction but not necessary for understanding.

Note that the omitted term is indispensable (the question is "What **is** your name?"), and its omission is only acceptable to the extent its implicit presence is clear from the context.

To the questions:

> Are both constructions correct according to normative grammar?

Yes, or rather both *can* be correct, as long as the omission doesn't hinder the understanding of the sentence. But in a formal context, especially in written form, it's important to apply this clarity criterion especially rigorously and, when in doubt, avoid the ellipsis.

> Is there any difference in meaning, even if subtle, between them?

The core meaning is the same, but the ellipsis tend to lend a more colloquial flavor to the sentence; it's also more concise — but the effect of that, if any, depends on context.

> What leads to one or the other being preferred?

As with other colloquial constructions, habit and (perceived) ease of use are the main motivations for its use.